Select2 optiongroup seleccionables
Estoy intentando hacer una pagina web para un proyecto de mi universidad, estoy utilizando el Select2 para poder buscar las opciones y elegir varios resultados dentro de la lista de opciones, pero una de las cosas que me pidieron fue que se pudiesen elegir los optgroup.
Si bien si se visualizan los datos y los optgroup son seleccionables, ocurre un pequeño bug en donde el Select2 no me deja buscar ninguna opción a menos que ya haya seleccionado algo, y yo creo que es porque tengo 2 etiquetas de Select2, osea, que se este inicializando 2 veces y por ello de error, la cosa, no se como poder unir ambos Select, ya lo he intentado antes y solo deja de mostrarme la información.
$('#lista').select2({
                placeholder: "Buscar por nombre completo...",
                allowClear: true,
                data: opciones,
                matcher: matchCustom, // Usa la función personalizada `matchCustom`
                
            });
        }

        $(function(){
      $.fn.select2.amd.require(["optgroup-data", "optgroup-results"],
          function (OptgroupData, OptgroupResults) {
          $('#lista').select2({
              dataAdapter: OptgroupData,
              resultsAdapter: OptgroupResults,
              allowClear: true
          });
      });
  });

No se si haya alguna forma para que se arregle este bug,

agrega datos de ejemplo para ver el comportamiento descripto. para inicializar varios select2 podes usar una class y un find().each() si necesitan cosas diferentes ( usando un attributo data por ej).
